# Equivalent of ng-init in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, angular, mean, mern, ng-init

I am converting my project from angular to reactjs. But I got stuck at ng-init. I don't know what is the equivalent of ng-init in reactjs in react way. Please help me, anyone, with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `componentDidMount` for class component

```
  componentDidMount() {
    ...
  }
```

The componentDidMount() method runs after the component output has been rendered to the DOM.

and use `useeffect` for the functional component

```
useEffect(() => {
 ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using class based components then its equivalent is ComponentWillMount() and if you're using function based component then it can be done in useEffect() hook provided by React.